# Silverlight import App.xaml from dynamically xap loaded

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, xap, app.xaml

Is there any way to access app.xaml resources of an imported XAP file (from host silverlight app) ???

Or better, import guest app.xaml into Host app.xaml

Problem is that in the imported Silverlight application, I lost all app.xaml resources, and I just see host resources... I would like to merge them...

It's possible?

I load XAP in this way

```
private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var manifestStream = Application.GetResourceStream(
        new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null),
        new Uri("AppManifest.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    string appManifest = new StreamReader(manifestStream.Stream).ReadToEnd();
    string assemblyName =m_rootAssembly + ".dll";
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(appManifest));
    Assembly asm = null;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement("AssemblyPart"))
        {
            reader.MoveToAttribute("Source");
            reader.ReadAttributeValue();
            if (reader.Value == assemblyName)
            {
                var assemblyStream = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, "application/binary");
                var si = Application.GetResourceStream(assemblyStream, new Uri(reader.Value, UriKind.Relative));
                AssemblyPart p = new AssemblyPart();
                asm = p.Load(si.Stream);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (asm == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not find specified assembly.");

    var o = asm.CreateInstance(m_typeName);
    if (o == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create instance of requested type.");

    RaiseXapLoadedEvent(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the uri of the resource file, like:
 "/*COMPONENTNAME*;component/*resourcepath*.xaml",

you can simply add this resource dictionary to your application by writing codes like:
`Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add("*resourceuri*");`

the "Application.Current" always points to the runtime application instance (host application), no matter where it is used.